# Gmail API "Watch" Quota

Tags: gmail-api

It would appear that setting a "watch" on a user mailbox is charged as 100 units on the Quota usage for the Gmail API. As far as I can tell, this is not listed on their quota page: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota or anywhere else I've been able to find.

Can someone verify this, and if it's documented anywhere that I've missed? I've noticed that I have this massively high quota usage well above what I should be for the number of requests I'm making to the endpoints I use in my application.

Comment: Yes you're right it is 100 units and wasn't documented. Docs updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric confirmed in the comments above that setting a watch does count as 100 units of Quota and that the documents have now been updated. Thanks!